# Hi, I'm trying to write code that will extract information from invoices that are saved as text files

Tags: python-3.x, parsing

```
    name = input("Enter file:")
    if len(name) < 1 : name = "AWM2.txt"
    handle = open(name)

    for line in handle:
        line = line.rstrip()
        type = re.findall('^\d{1,2}?.\d{1,2}?.\d{1,2}\s*', line)
        if len(type) > 0:
            print(type)
        #type = re.findall('.*\n.*\s([M].[W])', line)
        lift = re.findall('^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}\s*\d{1,5}\s*(\d{1,})\s.*\n.*[M].*[l]', line)
        if len(lift) > 0:
            print(line)
            print("Lift", lift)
            lifts = lifts + int(lift[0])
    print("Total Lifts", lifts)
```

What I'm struggling with is trying to 'findall' data that is spread over two lines, i.e. the number i want to count depends on the following line contains the text 'MMW Commercial', but not the lines that contain 'MDR Commercial'.  It's all going fine until my regex contains `\n` to look at the following line.  Any ideas to help?

I'm looking to extract a number from a text file, the text looks like this below, the first line is bold with the number I'm trying to extract, and italicised with the piece of text that specifies the correct number to extract.

```
XXX GROUP 
Supervalu 393
 Ardee Shopping Centre 
Ash Walk 
Ardee 
A92 W56E 

Invoice No.: OUT-10618 Invoice Date: 29-02-20 

Supervalu 393 (393), Ardee Shopping Centre, Ash Walk, Ardee, A92 W56E  
05/02/20  67879  **3** SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  127.95  
FC 22.00 _MMW Commercial_  66.00  
PPKG 0.1500 MMW Commercial 413 kg  61.95  
12/02/20  69770  5 SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  110.00  
FC 22.00 MMW Commercial  110.00  
PPKG 0.1500 MMW Commercial 0 kg  0.00  
19/02/20  71619  4 SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  128.50  
FC 22.00 MMW Commercial  88.00  
PPKG 0.1500 MMW Commercial 270 kg  40.50  
26/02/20  73458  4 SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  134.23  
FC 22.00 MMW Commercial  88.00  
PPKG 0.1605 MMW Commercial 288 kg  46.23  
Bin Services Sub Total: 500.68  
03/02/20  67077  2 SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  20.00  
FC 10.00 MDR Commercial  20.00  
10/02/20  69074  3 SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  30.00  
FC 10.00 MDR Commercial  30.00  
17/02/20  70884  3 SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  30.00  
FC 10.00 MDR Commercial  30.00  
24/02/20  72713  2 SLBIN 1100 (Customers Own Bin)  20.00  
FC 10.00 MDR Commercial  20.00  
Bin Services Sub Total: 100.00  
11/02/20  69381  1 SLBIN 1 (Baled)  113.78  
P/T 56.89 Packaging Cardboard Baled 2000 kg  113.78  
26/02/20  73007  1 SLBIN 1 (Baled)  204.80  
P/T 56.89 Packaging Cardboard Baled 3600 kg  204.80
```

Comment: are you sure your regex is correct? I'd recommend using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iwQGfa/1) to check that your regex is actually doing what you are expecting.

Comment: Yes, I ran the regex through regex101 already and it says it's correct.

Comment: well then are you searching the whole text or going through the file line by line and only checking if text that spreads over multiple lines can be found in that single line? You don't share all the relevent code but based on searching a variable called `line` I'd suspect that is your issue. You will obviously not find text spanning multiple lines if you are only scanning a single line at a time.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks Tadhg.  I am new to this - do you have a suggestion on how I might search better?  All the invoice items are in combinations of lines that start with a date - should i be making all those items into a line, or is there a better way of searching?

Comment: you need to provide a bit more code for me or anyone else to give a reasonable answer, right now all you are showing is applying the regex to a line.  I'd guess you could just do `data = file.read()` then do `findall` on the whole read text instead of looping through the lines. but again you need to share how you actually open and use the file.

Comment: I've put most of the code in above, Tadhg.  Thanks for your help, I'll plug away with your suggestions in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

you are iterating over the lines in your file

```
for line in handle:
```

just don't do that, read the whole file with `handle.read()` call `re.findall` on that string, `findall` returns a list so just iterate over the matches.

```
handle = open(name)
data = handle.read()
matches = re.findall('^\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}\s*\d{1,5}\s*(\d{1,})\s.*\n.*[M].*[l]', data)
for lift in matches:
    print("Lift", lift)
    lifts = lifts + int(lift)
for line in data.splitlines():
    # do what ever else you need line wise, if you still need something line wise.
print("Total Lifts", lifts)
```

Comment: Thanks Tadhg, sorry for the delay in getting back to you, I've been away.  I'll try that later today - thanks very much.